# How to put collection name in mongoose model

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

mY model,

```
       var CategorySchema = new Schema({
      categoryname: {
        type: String
      },
     topictitle: {
        type: String
      },
       topicdescription: {
        type: String
      },
      tag: {
        type: String
      },
      topicid: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId
      },
      user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
      }
   });
    mongoose.model('topics', CategorySchema);
```

Here topics is the name of my model but where can i keep my collection name?Can anyone suggest me help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the below model definition

> mongoose.model('topics', CategorySchema);

```
var topics = mongoose.model('topics', CategorySchema,'topics' );
var tags = mongoose.model('tags', TagSchema, 'topics');
```

'topics' (last parameter) is the collection name & CategorySchema is the structure of a particular document

Check Mongoose [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model)

Comment: ok,how can i call the model i.e where can i keep my model name

Comment: i have 5 models but only 1 collection,in that case i cant keep all name as same ,since it throws error ,collection is already registered

Comment: finally, the collection name and model name are same?

Comment: i have 2 models 1.tags 2.topics but both should go to same collection i.e topics

Comment: In this case my 2 models have like this  mongoose.model('topics', CategorySchema); ---for tags  and  mongoose.model('topics', CategorySchema);----for topics but if i run my code ,it shows error 'schema topics already registered same cannot be done twice'.So how to solve this.

Comment: Thank you so much,it helped me.